# Adding Ubuntu Studio components to existing Ubuntu Desktop installation

Tags: dual-boot, upgrade, amd-graphics

I have an old, late 2009 vintage, HP Pavilion dv6z-1100cto Artist Edition 2 laptop running Windows 7 Home Premium x64, AMD Turion X2 Ultra 64.

I need to transition to Linux as mainstream support for Windows 7 ends January 2020. Because I do photo and video editing with this machine, I was wondering if I could just install the regular Ubuntu Desktop and layer Ubuntu Studio over it?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the desired components with

```
sudo apt install ubuntustudio-photography
sudo apt install ubuntustudio-video
sudo apt install ubuntustudio-graphics
```

to your Ubuntu desktop.